# How to fill cylinder cap flatly?

Tags: modeling, edges, faces

[image]

I am trying to fill the top of this cylinder, but when I extrude in it isn't flat. Also, how can I make it so it extrudes evenly into the center? I hope I am not being too vague.

Comment: Look up 'Grid Fill' in the manual. That works nicely as the hole you're filling has an even number of edges. You can also specify the cap type of your cylinder when you create it in the 3d View Tool Shelf.  The "Make Edge/Face' tool is another option, but leaves you with an n-gon.

Comment: Try hitting [F], or [S] > [Shift]+[Z] > `0` > [Enter] > [W] > [R].